# Update mongodb collection record

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb

I'm playing around with node.js and mongo.db this weekend. At the moment I'm trying to update a record within a collection.

When the archiveuser function is called I'm getting a 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE' in the developertools console. I'm using a similar snippet to the archiveuser function to delete users and this works perfectly. I can't understand why this is now failing.

I've written this snippet of code to perform the update within users.js:

```
router.put('/updateuser/:id', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var userToUpdate = req.params.id;

    db.userlist.update({"_id" : userToUpdate}, 
        {
            $set:{'archived':'1'}
        })
});
```

Which is being called from global.js from this function:

```
function archiveUser(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'UPDATE',
        url: '/users/updateuser/' + $(this).attr('rel')
    }).done(function( response ) {

        // Check for a successful (blank) response
        if (response.msg === '') {
            alert('Success');
        }
        else {
            alert('Error: ' + response.msg);
        }
    });
};
```

If I was using php with mysql I would run an update query, similar to this.

```
UPDATE userlist
SET archived='1'
WHERE id=$usertodelete;
```

Any help is much appreciated

Tony

Comment: Your code looks correct. But only under the premise that `userToUpdate` is a correctly formated and valid ObjectId. Please veryify which string exactly is passed to `db.userlist.update`.

Comment: @Philipp - The string is 54654563c46d365a4c60ed98 , which matches a user id within the collection

Comment: Might it be a problem that your router binds to `/updateuser/[id]` while your ajax request is to `/users/updateuser/[id]`?

Comment: @Philipp I don't think so. The pattern matches the deleteuser route within users.js and its associated ajax call which are both in the same files as the above snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Philipp pointed out, the code is fine and works as expected.

The problem I was having is I didn't realise that the node server needed to be restarted with every change to a node.js js file (routes, app.js etc)

I have installed nodemon (https://github.com/remy/nodemon) which restarts the server whenever it detects a change. This combined with live reloading the web browser has solved the problem.